# Dropbox read only python api

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api

Hello i'm having a problem where i'm need api token to never expire but everytime it says "Token expired"

And i can't find a tutorial how to do that.
thanks.

I tried to watch dropbox tutorials but they never mentioned how to do that.

Comment: AFAIK most tokens have a limited lifespan. You probably need to refresh / replace the token on a regular basis. To help you, we need more details. Can you please [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]? What exact error do you get? (Include the stack trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox is no longer offering the option for creating new long-lived access tokens. Dropbox is switching to only issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens#updating-access-token-type).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.

For [the official Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python), you can find examples of this flow at the following links:

- https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-scopes.py
- https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-pkce.py